# chrome.devtools.network.getHAR returning 0 entries

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to build chrome plugin where I need to capture all the network requests triggered on a web page. I have gone through Docs @http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network.html

And I am using

```
    chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(
    function(harLog) {
        alert(harLog.entries.length);

});
```

But everytime I am getting 0 entries, even when I try to open panel first and refresh the web page. Can some please help if there is anything I am missing ??

I am using any webpage to test this e.g."http://www.cnn.com/" and have set permissions in manifest as

```
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
```

Comment: Why use `devtools` ? **[chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)** seems like a more useful approach.

Comment: Hey Expert System, this one helps. But is there anyway to read network requests only for currently active tab ?    Issue I am facing is current active tab will not be known from background page...  and file popup.js (specific to pageActionUI) can not attach listeners for network requests..

Comment: Yes below given example gives a good understanding. Thanks for your help it works

Comment: @ExpertSystem: glad your answer satisfied the OP's need.  But one reason for using chrome.devtools.network is to get full details of the request.  Google is discussing adding the ability for webRequest to return a response body, but that is currently impossible.  And webRequest requires 3 different listeners in order to get request header, request body, and response header - you can't get all 3 from  chrome.webRequest.onComplete.addListener as one would expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen for requests and do the filtering based on the `tabId` field. Of course, you need to keep track of the active tabs (one tab per window).
E.g.:

1. Use **[chrome.tabs.onActivated](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated)** to listen for changes in the active tab per widnow and store the `tabId` in a local variable.
2. Use **[chrome.windows.onRemoved](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onRemoved)** to stop tracking tabs for closed windows.
3. Register listener(s) for any of the **[chrome.webRequest.*](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#events)** events that suit your purpose. E.g. to get notified for any request in one of the active tabs as soon as the request is ready to be sent, register a listener for **[chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest)**.

---

Below is the source code of a sample extension that does exactly that.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "*://*/*"
    ]
}
```

**background.js:**

```
/* Keep track of the active tab in each window */
var activeTabs = {};

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(details) {
    activeTabs[details.windowId] = details.tabId;
});

/* Clear the corresponding entry, whenever a window is closed */
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(winId) {
    delete(activeTabs[winId]);
});

/* Listen for web-requests and filter them */
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.tabId == -1) {
        console.log("Skipping request from non-tabbed context...");
        return;
    }

    var notInteresting = Object.keys(activeTabs).every(function(key) {
        if (activeTabs[key] == details.tabId) {
            /* We are interested in this request */
            console.log("Check this out:", details);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });

    if (notInteresting) {
        /* We are not interested in this request */
        console.log("Just ignore this one:", details);
    }
}, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] });

/* Get the active tabs in all currently open windows */
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function(tabs) {
    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        activeTabs[tab.windowId] = tab.id;
    });
    console.log("activeTabs = ", activeTabs);
});
```

Comment: Thank You, it helped me successfully create my chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for your page download to finish before reading the HAR. Try something like this:

```
var interval = setInterval( function() {
                   clearInterval(interval);
                   chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(
                          function(harLog) {
                              alert(harLog.entries.length);
                          });               
                    }, 5000 );
```

This will wait 5 seconds before reading the HAR.